# Purpose of using binding source?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I recieve some information about using binding source but I really don't understand explicitly why using binding source related to datagridview.

My questions are:

- Advantage and disadvantage of using bindingsource instead of removing the third person that is between the datasource and data gridview?
- What context are you supposed to use binding source?

Comment: Your question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Please explain more! I still don't understand what part you don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Binding source can provide some additional logic that you want to protect your model. The most natural example is transaction logic or the ability to cancel changes.

When you're binding a control to a datasource directly all changes take place immediately. With a binding source between these two you have the ability to cancel or save edit, to buffer changes etc.